# Django-esque way to let users preview uploaded data?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using Django forms and would like to allow users to upload a CSV file of pupils, perform some server-side validation, and preview their data before submitting it to the database. I have a question about the most Django-esque way to do this.

My code is currently as follows:

```
def import_pupils(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PupilUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = csv.DictReader(request.FILES['file_upload'])
            # Check for non-form errors - e.g. pupils not found in 
            # our existing database. Clean data and create master list. 
            pupils = ....
            # Show preview page and/or warning messages... on a new page?
            return render_to_response('preview_data.html', 
                { pupils : pupils, warning_messages: messages }, 
                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
            form = PupilUploadForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = PupilUploadForm()
    return render_to_response('pupil_upload.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If there are no errors, my preview page `preview_data.html` displays a table of the data, all packed up in `pupils`. My next step is to add a link/button to save all this to the database. The code I will use to add the data is:

```
for pupil in pupils:
    Pupil.objects.get_or_create(pupil=pupil['name'], teacher=pupil['teacher'])
```

My question is basically: where should that line go? What is the most Django-esque way to handle this? My data is all packed up ready in the `pupils` list, and I just want to `get_or_create` it, but should I use a link to a new view function, a new form on `preview_data.html`...? It seems inefficient to pass data to the new page and then re-import it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making this a two-step process:

1. First, save the uploaded file to some temporary location, then do
   your validation and display the data (including any validation
   errors)
2. If the user chooses to save the file, import the records from the
   already uploaded file and save to the database, then delete the
   file.

If you'd rather not use a temporary file, you could create a temporary table, and import the records in there. Then, either copy them to the actual table (if the user accepts) or delete them.